# python 'socket' has no attribute 'CAN_J1939'

Tags: python, can-bus, j1939

just making a pretty straightforward J1939 reader with the `socket` library:

```py
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.PF_CAN, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.CAN_J1939) as s:
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    addr = "can3", socket.J1939_NO_NAME, socket.J1939_NO_PGN, socket.J1939_NO_ADDR
    s.bind(addr)

    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(128)
        print(f'{addr[3]:02x} {addr[2]:05x}')

        for j in range(len(data)):
            if j % 8 == 0 and j != 0:
                print(f'\n{j:05x}    ')
            print(f'{j:02x}')
        print('\n')
```

running this give me this error:

> AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'CAN_J1939'

i'm not sure why the heck this error is firing.  i have `can-utils` installed and a couple other J1939 libs when i wrote the Buildroot, so i don't know why this is popping up.  plus, i'm running v3.10 on the SoC and the `CAN_J1939` has be available since v3.5.  :P  don't even know how to troubleshoot this one...  O_o

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.CAN_J1939) it's available on linux versions >= 5.4 and python versions >= 3.9

Comment: yup.  and, as i mentioned, i'm running 3.10.

Comment: And the linux kernel version?

Comment: 5.4.201, also within range.  (it's an SoC, SingleCore, SingleProc.)

Comment: i should note, this thing was *supposed* to be built expressly for reading various digital and analog signals, CANBUS/J1939 among them.  so this kinda surprises me.